# Вопрос про маршруты в Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте.
У меня возникла такая проблема: при попытке редактирования поста появляется вот такая ошибка:

```
undefined method `post_path' for
```

Вот код в контроллере Posts:

```
def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

Вот routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
    resources :posts
end
```

Вот ссылка, которая ведет на форму с редактированием:

```
<%= link_to 'Редактировать', edit_user_post_path %>
```

Ну и сама форма, при переходе на которую возникает эта ошибка (файл edit.html.erb):

> <%= form_for @post do |f| %> и тд. (в качестве ошибки указывается эта
>   строка)

**UPDATE**
Методом тыка изменил форму на

```
<%= form_for :post, url: user_post_path(:post), method: :put do |f| %>
```

а в контроллере оставил метод `edit` пустым:

```
 def edit
 end
```

Теперь все работает и вопрос закрыт. Но на русрейлс метод `edit` не пустой, форма такая:

```
<%= form_for :post, url: post_path(@post.id), method: :patch do |f| %>
```

Может это в новых 4 рельсах так можно? На 3 не работает так.

Comment: Уточните два аспекта:
1. Какая у вас версия рельса в проекте?
2. Используете ли вы Devise или у вас свой велосипед?

Comment: 1. 3.2.14 2. Свой. :)

Answer (score 3):

Возможно Вам стоит заменить

```
<%= link_to 'Редактировать', edit_user_post_path %>
```

на

```
<%= link_to 'Редактировать', edit_post_path(@post) %>
```

или

```
<%= link_to 'Редактировать', edit_user_post_path(@post) %>
```